# WPF: Change a value from a template

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want a value which is inside a *template* to change while some trigger happens. I can't access it through the style trigger's for some reason. How do I achieve that?

example:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="iconButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Margin="5">
                        <Ellipse Width="45" Height="45" Fill="White" Opacity="0"/>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center">hello</TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <!--TODO - change the "opacity" of the ellipse. 
                Maybe binding is necessary? -->
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I would like to change the `opacity` property of the `ellipse` (which is inside the `style`'s `template`) while overing the button with the mouse.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You may also want to show the Button's Content in the TextBlock in the ControlTemplate: `<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" .../>`. Or better, replace the TextBlock by a ContentPresenter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Style Triggers use ControlTemplate Triggers. Refer below code.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="iconButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Margin="5">
                            <Ellipse Width="45" x:Name="EllipseControl" Height="45" Fill="White" Opacity="0"/>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Center">hello</TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="EllipseControl" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>               
        </Style>
```